# Problemas al mostrar los datos en fullcalendar

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

Tengo el siguiente problema con `fullcalendar` al mostrar los datos que obtengo desde una base de datos.

Recibo en mi aplicación de `Angular` estos datos desde el backend.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "idCita": "2",
            "fechaCita": "2022-03-15 12:00:00",
            "tiempoCita": "30",
            "idCliente": "2",
            "idEmpleado": "1",
            "servicioCita": "",
            "created_at": "2022-03-12 06:17:05",
            "updated_at": "2022-03-12 06:17:05",
            "deleted_at": null
        }
    ]
```

Luego en mi aplicación los paso por el `forEach` para obtener los datos según utiliza `fullcalendar` teniendo en cuenta esta `interface`

```
export interface EventosCalendar {
  title: string;
  start: string;
  end?: string;
  allDay?: boolean;
}
```

Este es el método que genera mis datos

```
  getEventos() {
    this.calendarService.getCitas().subscribe((resp) => {
      let datos = resp.data;

      datos.forEach((dt: Citas) => {
        let kk: EventosCalendar = {
          title: dt.idCliente,
          start: moment(dt.fechaCita).toISOString(),
        };

        if (dt.tiempoCita != undefined) {
          kk.end = moment(dt.fechaCita)
            .add(dt.tiempoCita, 'minute')
            .toISOString();
        } else {
          if (moment(dt.fechaCita).hour() == 0) {
            kk.allDay = true;
          }
        }

        this.events.push(kk);
      });
      
    });
  
  }
```

Al parecer todo esta bien, solo que los eventos no se muestran en el calendario. Realice algunas otras pruebas para buscar si existía algún problema teniendo en cuenta el ciclo de vida de angular, para ello cree una colección de datos manual de esta manera, en el mismo método,

```
 this.eventos2 = [
      {
        end: '2022-03-15T17:30:00.000Z',
        start: '2022-03-15T17:00:00.000Z',
        title: '2',
      },
    ];
```

y estos si se muestran sin problemas en calendario. Acá les muestro el console.log de ambos arreglos de datos y son los mismo. Tanto los parcheados manualmente, como los traídos desde la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando utilizo los datos estáticos se muestran en el calendario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si utilizo los datos de la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El único cambio ocurre aquí

```javascript
 initCalendar() {
    this.calendarOptions = {
      timeZone: 'America/Bogota',
      initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
      locale: esLocale,
      events: this.events, //aqui cambio los datos a usar
      rerenderDelay: 5,
      nowIndicator: true,
      lazyFetching: true,
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next,today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth,listWeek',
      },
      eventClick: this.showProgramacion.bind(this),
      dateClick: this.setSpecificDate.bind(this),
    };
  }
```

Acá se muestra además el objeto del calendario en consola, donde se ve que los datos están en el mismo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema probablemente esté relacionado con la detección de cambios.
Como estás mutando el array de la propiedad `events` usando `this.events.push(kk);`  cuando recibes la respuesta, la referencia de dicho array no varía y `fullcalendar` no detecta el cambio.

Prueba refactorizando tu código usando el método `map` en vez de `forEach`, ya que este crea un nuevo array.

Tu código quedaría así.

```
getEventos() {
    this.calendarService.getCitas().subscribe((resp) => {
      let datos = resp.data;

      this.events = datos.map((dt: Citas) => { 
        let kk: EventosCalendar = {
          title: dt.idCliente,
          start: moment(dt.fechaCita).toISOString(),
        };

        if (dt.tiempoCita != undefined) {
          kk.end = moment(dt.fechaCita)
            .add(dt.tiempoCita, 'minute')
            .toISOString();
        } else {
          if (moment(dt.fechaCita).hour() == 0) {
            kk.allDay = true;
          }
        }

        return kk;
      });
      this.calendarOptions.events = this.events; // adicioné esto a tu código
    });
  
  }
```

un saludo

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, con tu cambio funciono parcialmente, ya que en este caso se quedaba el calendario sin los eventos, voy a editar tu respuesta, con el cambio que adicioné para que los datos fueran asignados a los eventos del calendario

Comment: Un  seguidor nuevo en tu canal de Youtube

Comment: @RodolfoBarbeitoRodriguez aceptado el cambio y gracias por la sub. un saludito

Answer (score 0):

También sería posible hacer uso de la clase ChangeDetectorRef.
He invocarlo mediante detectChanges() una vez que tuvieras el vector completo.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).